# WKWebView Mac OS disabling user interaction

Tags: swift, xcode, wkwebview

**How to figure out the requirement to disable all user interaction over the content loaded by WKWebView?**
I did not find out any proper method or attribute, so I falled to the idea to put any other but transparent view over the webview. Unfortunatelly, without success. Is there any common way how to solve such issue?

Answer (score 1):

this works for me...

```
public class WebViewWhichIgnoresTheMouse: WKWebView
{
    override public func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent)
    {
        self.nextResponder?.scrollWheel(with: event)
    }
    
    override public func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent)
    {
        self.nextResponder?.mouseDown(with: event)
    }
    
    override public func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent)
    {
        self.nextResponder?.mouseUp(with: event)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you tired this ?

```
self.wkwebView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Or use this method

```
func removeTapGestures() {
    for subView in self.scrollView.subviews {
        if let recogniserz = subView.gestureRecognizers {
            for recogniser in recogniserz {
                if recogniser is UITapGestureRecognizer {
                    subView.removeGestureRecognizer(recogniser)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried, but got `Value of type 'WKWebView?' has no member 'isUserInteractionEnabled'`. It is probably that I am on Mac OS, not on iOS?

Comment: At the end of the day, with playing around @Shauket suggestion, I ended up with `let subviews = self.superview?.subviews
        print(subviews!.count)
        subviews?.forEach({
            $0.gestureRecognizers.removeAll()
            $0.enclosingScrollView?.gestureRecognizers.removeAll()
        })` but without success to disable anything...

Comment: on `WKWebView` is attached `NSImmediateActionGestureRecognizer` which I cannot find out any documentation about anywhere (probably it is that one, listening initializers first gesture sender). I am starting to be pretty sure, that this way, **for Mac OS**, is too long and too uncertain :/

Comment: At least you got the way

Comment: After removing `NSImmediateActionGestureRecognizer` the behavior of `WKWebView` will remain the same (fully interactive). So I don't think I got the way.

Comment: You arr removing from loadef webview in didfinish delegate function?

Comment: Yes, exactly`func webView(_: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.removeGestureRecognizers()
    }`

Comment: I resolved my problem by "dedicated solution", I guess. Principialy it was inherit `WKWebView` and override its mouse events (it was the only I needed). But I think, it is not a solution of the problem asked above. It still remains and I think it is by logic how different behave `NSView` and `UIView` where @Shauket suggestion I believe works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah remove touches the way to restrict user to disable long touch or normal touches on all scrollviews. There are others ways as well like to disable tocuh through js code i tried them but that not worked